# How can I create this kind of scroll view in flutter also I want the shadow and magnification I am very confused

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]
I am creating a music app for that I need.

I dont know any way to do this things.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the [carusel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package.

If you are new to flutter, my **best advice is**:
Look for stuff like that on pub.dev for packages. Mostly there are some packages witch you can use pretty easily.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how do I create exact scroll view like that shows some part of the 1 one then full 2 and then about 80% of the 3rd one